# Is there a way to create a RSA key with a small public key?

Tags: javascript, performance, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption

In RSA I have basically 3 numbers: `d`, `e`, `n`

The public key is `(e, n)`, and private key is `(d, n)`

The server will sign a number `m` by calculating `c=m^d mod n` and the client will decrypt the signature by calculating `m=c^e mod n`.

In my situation the computational powers of the client are limited (it is happening in Javascript within the browser) - and I would like to make the public key operations as efficient as possible.

So my question is - is there a way to generate an RSA key `(d, e, n)` such that the security of the system is still high - but the public key operation performance is good?

Is there a way to make the number `e` in the public key small (maybe 64 bits), and large numbers `n` and `d` (maybe 1024-bits or 2048-bits).

I randomly generated some large keys and tested the performance of some javascript RSA library, and the performance was extremely bad. Keys of size 1024 bits take forever to compute.

The library I used was taken from [here](http://www.ohdave.com/rsa/)

Maybe my problem is the library I'm using has a poor performing algorithm??

I need the public key operation to be fast, and I don't want to sacrifice on security.

Comment: Fast encryption =  weak encryption. Generally, the time to decrypt is proportional to the time to encrypt.

Comment: Yes, the encrypt exponent can be small. Most applications simply set e to 65537.

Comment: I don't understand, how do you choose d and n when you assume that e is a particular number?

Comment: Never mind, I found this site that can give me a random key with 65537 as the e value here http://www.mobilefish.com/services/rsa_key_generation/rsa_key_generation.php

Comment: @codefactor: It is not difficult at all. 1) choose e, in this case e=65537. 2) find two large primes p and q such that gcd(e, p-1) = gcd(e, q-1) = 1. 3) find d using the extended euclidean algorithm. Step 2 will succeed very quickly for e=65537, and will succeed somewhat less quickly (but quickly enough!) for e=3.

Comment: If you want fast encryption, just choose e=3 and compute the associated d. But make sure you use a proper RSA padding, namely OAEP.

Comment: RSA key generation is expensive. The RSA public key operation is very cheap. Decryption is more expensive with RSA than encryption but still reasonable. With Diffie-Hellman key-gen, encryption and decryption have similar cost which is somewhere between RSA encryption and decryption.